# Having a delay for ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, ng-style

I'm using ng-style to set the width of an element, like so:

```
<div ng-style="{ width: calculateWidth(item.shares,'shares') }"></div>
```

The function that I'm using in my controller:

```
  $scope.calculateWidth = function(input,type){
    var width = input / maxObject[type] * 100;
    if (isNaN(width)) return 0
    else return width+'%'
  }
```

Now I'd like to animate this width by using a CSS transition on the element. 
But when I use it this way, the width of the result is already applied when the element is rendered and so no transition is displayed.

I've tried using a $timeout in the calculateWidth function, but then the function does not work at all and the resulting width's are all 0.

Is it possible to delay the applying of this ng-style in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Bind your style expression to a scope variable, and then modify that item inside a `$timeout` call.

```
<div ng-style="item.style"></div>
```

Then in Angular, the style gets applied after a 2 second delay (looping over the collection of items).

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.forEach(itemList, function(item) {
        item.style = { width: $scope.calculateWidth(item.shares, 'shares') };
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this: These elements are generated in an ng-repeat, so item.shares is a value that I'm passing to the controller from the view. Any way I can do this with your proposed solution?